# Sed script to update a version number in an RPM SPECS file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a specs file:

```
Name:           program
Version:        2.3.3
Release:        0
...
```

I want to update the version number every time it's built. I perform the build from a bash script so I'm calling `sed` to update the SPECS file and a "version" file which holds the version number.

I am using the following sed script to perform the update:

```sh
sed -ri 's/^(Version:\s+)([0-9.]+)/\1$version/g' SPECS/*.spec
```

with the `$version` being provided by the bash script.

It's designed to look for the correct line and replace the version portion while preserving whatever whitespace has been used. I use `*.spec` so that it will work with a spec file of any name.

I felt that a sed one-liner made the most sense given the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables don't interpolate inside single quotes.  You need double quotes.

No need to capture the old version that we're throwing away. The `/g` is redundant since the pattern can never match more than once per line (being anchored to start-of-line).

What happens with `Version: 0.9a`?  `Version:1`?  `Version:`?  Better to take the whole line, possibly excluding comments, and relax the space requirement.

```
sed -ri'' "s/^(Version:\s*)[^#]*/\1$version/" SPECS/*.spec
```

It's possible for the description or another section to contain the trigger text, and we probably don't want to change that.  Use sed's `start,stop` addressing to limit replacement to the top block only, stopping at the first `%whatever` header:

```
sed -ri'' "1,/^\s*%/s/^(Version:\s*)[^#]*/\1$version/" SPECS/*.spec
```

Note that `-i''` is a GNU/BSD portable way to disable backup file.